# use variable in if statement operator in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a variable that contains either `'&&'` or `'||'` and I need to use it in an if statement like so.

```
operator = '&&'

result = 1===1 operator 2===2

#=> result = 1===1 && 2===2
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried using `#public_send` but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do it this way? While you can use Object#send for methods, you can't do the same thing without eval for keywords and operators.

Comment: @ToddAJacobs : You can do public_send for nearly all operators (for instance `2.public_send(:+, 5)` works fine), but `&&` is an exception. For the same reason, you can't override it for a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```rb
operator = "&&"
result = eval "1===1 #{operator} 2===2"
```

does that do what you want?

or if `1===1` is just a placeholder here for some expression, assign the result to a variable, so:

```rb
operator = "&&"
a = 1===1
b = 2===2
result = eval "#{a} #{operator} #{b}"
```

(of course, as commenters have noted, you must pay attention to the security vulnerabilities of `eval`, e.g. check that the operator variable is either `"&&"` or `"||"`.)

and if you really want an `if` statement:

```rb
if operator == '&&'
  1===1 && 2===2
elsif operator == '||'
  1===1 || 2===2
else
  # dunno
end
```

Comment: I hope you realize this comes with a giant blinking **WARNING** on it as `eval` exposes you to extraordinary levels of risk.

Comment: @Brad Where is `operator` coming from? Was the value of that variable provided by a user of your application? Do you trust that user? I am asking because imagine what will happen if `operation` was a string like `; FileUtils.remove_dir(...);`?

Comment: @LesNightingill : Don't do eval, unless you have no other choice.

Comment: @tadman, @LesNightingill : Is there a way to ensure before `eval` that `operator`, `a` and `b` are safe for the `eval`? That is, limit the user input to only the "safe" type.

Answer (score 6):

The `&&` operator is more of a low-level syntax element than `&` and `|` which are method calls. That makes it harder to do.

However, there's two ways:

```
a = true
b = false
c = true
```

If you want `&&` equivalence:

```
[ a, b, c ].all?
# => false
[ a, c ].all?
# => true
```

If you want `||` equivalence:

```
[ a, b, c ].any?
# => true
[ a, b ].any?
# => true
[ b ].any?
# => false
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the problem. The project I'm working on implements a user generated list of conditions that I need to test based on the operator the user selected. So the resulting if statement may contain a mixture of && and ||

Comment: This solves the problem you described. If you have a broader problem then it's worth asking a new question to address that, but be sure to be specific about the true scope of it.

Comment: It was specific, how to use a string variable as an operator, with an example. I appreciate your response, but in this case it didn't solve the actually question asked. No need to be salty.

Comment: Moving the goalposts is always a bit of a jerk move. Your question strongly implies there is one and only one operator. To be sure everyone's on the same page, always try and express the requirements more comprehensively, including edge cases that need to be covered. It's far from clear where you're taking this and how the `any?` or `all?` approach will break down.

Comment: I didn't move the goal posts, you just made an assumption about what I was doing or why I was doing it rather than just looking at the example and answering the question. But it's all good. I got the answer and I'm sure your answer will help someone in the future. No need to take it so personally :) Again, thanks for your answer, I do appreciate it.

Comment: The answer, hopefully, isn't `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use public_send, but even if it were allowed with &&, it would not make sense. Note that `E1 && E2` shortcircuits, in that E2 is not evaluated if E1 is already falsy. How could this work with `public_send`?

If you want to have this effect, you have to give up shortcircuiting, which means that you have to use `&` and `|` instead of `&&` and `||`. If you insist that your variable `operator` contains something like `'&&'`, and not, say `:&` (which would make more sense), you could do a

```
result = (1===1).public_send(operator[0], 2===2)
```

to use your example for demonstration.

**UPDATE**: The comment of tadman to my answer made me think that I should warn you about the following trap: Based on your question, I assumed that the arguments you want to connect with your operator are either `true` or `false`. In this case, my solution indeed should work. However, if you they can be just any *truey* or *falsy* value of some class *X*, you need to convert them to *true* or *false*, because otherwise, the operator may have a different interpretation (for instance, if you operands happen to be integer). Hence, for some general operand_e1_ and *e2*, which - as is the general rule in Ruby - are supposed to be interpreted als false if it is either `false` or `nil`, and is taken as true otherwise, the safe way to calculate your result would be

```
result = (!!e1).public_send(operator[0], !!e2)
```

where `!!` ensures that the expressions are converted to `true` and `false` so that the operators `&` and `|` can safely be applied.

Comment: `&` is very different from `&&`.

Comment: @tadman : In general, yes, but in the scope of the OPs question, it is the same, because he (1) Does not want to have the short circuit feature of &&, and (2) Both of his arguments are _boolean_, i.e. either `true` or `false`. But you are right that here danger is lurking, and I will amend my answer.

Comment: I'm just not sure that this will work at all. You can't `send(:&&, ...)` to anything.

Comment: @tadman : You can't, and I don't. I'm doing a `send(:&,...)` instead, which for our case is sufficient, since we don't need `&&` here.

Comment: Except that `&` is completely different from `&&`.

Comment: @tadman : Not **completely**, as I explained in the update to my answer. `a && x && (b=c)` would be different, while `(!!a) & (!!c)` would deliver the same result for any variable `a` and `c`. The differences should be clear from my answer, and in particular in the scope of the question, I don't see any difference. Aside from this, I like your suggestion to map the operator strings which the OP wants to use, into `:any?` or `:all?`, and apply this symbol, better than my approach, but both work and it is up to the OP to choose what fits him better.